# Error Compiling in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, compilation, conditional-statements

I have to make a program that checks all the numbers before an user defined number, and store the prime ones. For now I am trying to make a program that checks if those numbers are prime or not, but I am getting an error code at compiling:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int *array;
int i,j,n;
array = malloc(sizeof(int));

printf("Ingrese su numero:");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=2;i<n;i+=1){
    for(j=2;j<=i;j+=1){
        if (i%j==0) $$ (j!=i){
            printf("%d: No Primo \n+",i);
            break;
        }
        else if (i=j){
            printf("%d: Primo \n+",i);
        }
    }
}



return 0;
}
```

And it throws

```
Line 15  error: expected ';' before '}' token
```

And I can't see anything wrong. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if (i%j==0) $$ (j!=i){` What do you expect this line to do??

Comment: @user3502583, you can try clang or newer gcc, they should have better error reporting (non-cryptic).

Comment: user3502583, if the problem is solved, you can select best answer and press "v"-shaped symbol left to it to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that one of your if statements is missing parenthesis (also, I assume you meant to use && not $$):

```
    if ((i%j==0) && (j!=i)){
        printf("%d: No Primo \n+",i);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Oh my god i am so silly, thanks ^^

Answer (score 2):

Where does one start?

See comments and I cannot be bothered to fix the indenatioon

```
but i am getting an error code at compiling:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int *array;
int i,j,n;
array = malloc(sizeof(int));

printf("Ingrese su numero:");
scanf("%d",&n); // check the return value - read the manual page

for(i=2;i<n;i+=1){ // use ++ operator
    for(j=2;j<=i;j+=1){ // ditto
        if (i%j==0) $$ (j!=i){ // what is $$ perhaps && + fix your brackets
            printf("%d: No Primo \n+",i);
            break;
        }
        else if (i=j){ // assignment operator perhaps == required
            printf("%d: Primo \n+",i);
        }
    }
}



return 0;
```

Comment: And that just fixed my second error, thanks ^^

Comment: Forgot to mention why have `array` and never use it?

Answer (score 0):

Your line `if (i%j==0) $$ (j!=i)` is wrong.  I think you mean `if (i%j==0 && j!=i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $$ with && in the if condition and place the both conditions in parenthesis

```
 if ((i%j==0) &&  (j!=i)){
            printf("%d: No Primo \n+",i);
            break;
        }
```